# I'm looking for two euclidean polytopes such that their cartesian product is no longer a euclidean polytope.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I'm looking for two euclidean convex polytopes such that their cartesian product is no longer a euclidean convex polytope.

Does such a thing exist?

Note here by convex polytope I mean the set $ K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that is cut out by finitely many half planes, with the additional constraint that $K$ is bounded by some $n$-ball.

Answer (score 1):

Well, boundness and convexity are preserved by the cartesian product in your case. Also, you can say that $K' = \{x: A'x' \leq b'\}$ and $K'' = \{x'':A''x''\leq b''\}$ are your two polytopes, so obviously
$$
  K'\times K'' = \{x:Ax \leq b\}
$$
where $x = [x' x'']$, $A = [A' A'']$ and $b = [b' b'']$.